# How to pass dynamic configuration values to super method of Passport Bearer Strategy NestJs

Tags: nestjs, passport-azure-ad, nestjs-passport

I'm trying to write a validator class using passport-azure-ad to validate all the request to my APIs.

I have extended the PassportStrategy class and configured it as a global guard. Everything working fine.
But now I have requirement to validate the request from different UI application from various domains. The problem here is clientId and tenantId will be different for each UI application hence the token they are passing in the header needs to validate against corresponding clientId and identityMetadata.

every request will have a param called **appname** in the header and based on the appname I need to fetch the passport configuration from the database for each application.

Is there any better way to implement this approach.

Below is the PassportStrategy class I have written

```html
import { AuthGuard, PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { BearerStrategy } from 'passport-azure-ad';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';


@Injectable()
export class AzureADStrategy extends PassportStrategy(BearerStrategy, 'azure-ad-bearer') {
  constructor(dbService: DbService) {
  //const appName = request.headers['appname']
  //const metaData = await dbService.getTokenMetaData(appName)
    super({
      identityMetadata: metaData.identity,
      jwtIssuer: metaData.issuer,
      clientID: metaData.clientId,
      validateIssuer: true,
      passReqToCallback: false,
      loggingLevel: 'info',
      loggingNoPII: false
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any): Promise<any> {
    return payload;
  }
}

export const AzureADGuard = AuthGuard('azure-ad-bearer');
```

In the above code the two commented line is my logic to implement,

1. But how the request can be accessed in the constructor ?
2. super() should be the first call in the constructor in that case how can i call my dbService to get data from DB ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I will try to show the standard practice (in theory) for using passport strategies.

1. You don't access things from the constructor except for any configService you may have implemented for it. You will want to implement that and then grab environment variables from it such as identity, issuer etc (your "metadata"). See [NestJs docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) for example of implementation of configuration service
2. Any sort of side-effect (like calling redis, or sql db or similar) should be done inside your validate() method. Check exactly what parameters (payload) that method receives and use those to verify and validate the incoming request against your personal logic.

Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'll clear my exact requirement.  Eg:- App1(react ui app) is calling my API, the request header will have a parameter `"appname": "App1"`. Based on this appname i need to fetch application specific client ids from DB. In other words. App1 will have ClientId1, App2 has ClientId2 etc. As you said I cannot put this app specific client ids in a configuration file, because these data is coming to my DB from an external source.

Comment: Two points I need to know here is.

`1. How can i call a db service before the super() method get executed.`
`2. How to access the http header before calling that db service.`

Comment: well, you can't and really shouldn't call the db service before super. i believe you should do all this in the verify method. it is possible that the specific strategy is not correct for you and you should possibly be using a simpler strategy